# Simplifying repetitive drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to use `\foreach` to simplify the following code.

I intentionally used tikzpictures without spaces between end and begin commands to display the graphs beside each other.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.4}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (3.5,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi>0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Skewed to left} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,0) +(90:\incrmnt*2) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,0) +(90:\incrmnt*3) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,0) +(90:\incrmnt*4) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,0) +(90:\incrmnt*5) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,0) +(90:\incrmnt*6) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,0) +(90:\incrmnt*7) -- +(-90:.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.4}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (3.5,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi=0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Symmetric} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,0) +(90:\incrmnt*2) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,0) +(90:\incrmnt*3) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,0) +(90:\incrmnt*4) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,0) +(90:\incrmnt*3) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,0) +(90:\incrmnt*2) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.4}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (3.5,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi<0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Skewed to right} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,0) +(90:\incrmnt*7) -- +(-90:0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,0) +(90:\incrmnt*6) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,0) +(90:\incrmnt*5) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,0) +(90:\incrmnt*4) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,0) +(90:\incrmnt*3) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,0) +(90:\incrmnt*2) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the answer of AndréC, I managed to use the following code

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.4}
%Axis
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (\incrmnt*9,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi>0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Skewed to left} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);

\draw [thick,-latex](\incrmnt*10,0) -- (\incrmnt*10*2,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi=0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Symmetric} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](\incrmnt*10,0) -- (\incrmnt*10,4);

\draw [thick,-latex](\incrmnt*10*2+\incrmnt,0) -- (\incrmnt*10*2+\incrmnt*10,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi<0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Skewed to right} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](\incrmnt*10*2+\incrmnt,0) -- (\incrmnt*10*2+\incrmnt,4);
%Curves
\foreach \y in {1,...,7}{\draw [ultra thick, linecolor] (\incrmnt*\y,0) +(90:\incrmnt*\y) -- +(-90:0);}

\begin{scope}[xshift=\incrmnt*10*30]
\foreach \y in {1,...,4}{\draw [ultra thick, linecolor] (\incrmnt*\y,0) +(90:\incrmnt*\y*1.5) -- +(-90:0);}
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yy using int(8-\y)] in {5,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\y,0) +(90:\incrmnt*\yy*1.5) -- +(-90:0);
}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=\incrmnt*10*30*2]
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yy using int(8-\y)] in {1,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\y,0) +(90:\incrmnt*\yy) -- +(-90:0);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: `\foreach \x in {1,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\x*\incrmnt,0) +(90:\x*\incrmnt) -- +(-90:0);
}`

Comment: @ Sigur Thank you for your suggestion. But I could not produce the other 2 drawings by it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first and third graphs can use a foreach loop. As for the second, it is possible but not very useful. Personally, I find it too small to be really profitable.

### Update:

Instead of placing 3 `tikzpicture` environments side by side without space, it is easier to fully use the power of TikZ and place the last two graphs in a `scope` environment and move it to the right.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.4}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (3.5,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi>0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Skewed to left} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {1,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\y,0) +(90:\incrmnt*\y) -- +(-90:0);
}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (3.5,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi=0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Symmetric} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,0) +(90:\incrmnt*2) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,0) +(90:\incrmnt*3) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,0) +(90:\incrmnt*4) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,0) +(90:\incrmnt*3) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,0) +(90:\incrmnt*2) -- +(-90:.0);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,0) +(90:\incrmnt*1) -- +(-90:.0);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (3.5,0) node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {$\pi<0.5$} node [pos=.5, black, xshift=0cm, yshift=3.4cm] {Skewed to right} node [xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] { };
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yy using int(8-\y)] in {1,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\y,0) +(90:\incrmnt*\yy) -- +(-90:0);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: graphes]

Comment: @Hany I improved the code by using only one `tikzpicture` environment and two `scope` environments.

Comment: @ AndréC  Thank you very much for your answer and its update. I managed to draw the middle one by combining both of your codes for 1 and 2. \begin{scope}[xshift=\incrmnt*10*30]
\foreach \y in {1,...,4}{\draw [ultra thick, linecolor] (\incrmnt*\y,0) +(90:\incrmnt*\y*1.5) -- +(-90:0);}
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yy using int(8-\y)] in {5,...,7}{
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\y,0) +(90:\incrmnt*\yy*1.5) -- +(-90:0);
}
\end{scope}

Comment: @ AndréC Please refer to my edited post. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hany Yes, it is feasible, but the question that needs to be asked is: Does it make the code easier to read? Is making two small loops easier than a simple copy and paste?

Comment: @ AndréC It does not make the code easier to read. But it is my trial to understand your line of thinking and using it. Thank you very much for your time and effort. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Hany You're right, it's by doing it yourself that you progress.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to AndréC's nice answer, inspired by pgfplots loading behavior. ;-) It has not a single visible loop, but is nonetheless shorter. ;-)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\emph{Now} I know why you're always loading \texttt{pgfplots} ;-)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black}]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by
2, x descriptions at=edge bottom,},xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5,ymax=8,height=4cm,width=5cm,
axis lines=left,title style={font=\small,anchor=north}]
\nextgroupplot[xtick={},ytick=\empty,
xlabel={$\pi>0.5$},title={Skewed to the left}]
\addplot [samples at={0,...,7},ycomb,no marks,linecolor] {x};
\nextgroupplot[xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
xlabel={$\pi=0.5$},title={Symmetric}]
\addplot [samples at={0,...,7},ycomb,no marks,linecolor]
{x+ifthenelse(x>3,7-2*x,0)};
\nextgroupplot[xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
xlabel={$\pi<0.5$},title={Skewed to the right}]
\addplot [samples at={0,...,7},ycomb,no marks,linecolor] {7-x};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ marmot Thank you very much for your time and effort.