# Simplifying repetitive drawings and nodes placing

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

How to apply the following code, from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457159/simplifying-repetitive-drawings-and-node-placing) (which gives the first drawing) to draw the second and third drawings

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\hspace {-1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape,linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black},dotline/.style={thin, black, loosely dotted},
point/.style={circle, draw, red, fill=red, scale=0.4},
cercle/.style={circle,draw,scale=.5, red,thick, fill=white,inner sep=6pt}
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.6}

%draw the axes of the left graph
\draw [thick,-latex](-.3,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3) -- (0,8);

%draw the graph itself
\foreach \y in {1,...,12}{\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*\y) node (yhl){} +(0:.15cm) -- +(180:.15cm) node [left] {\y/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*\y) -- +(0:8*\incrmnt);}
\foreach \x in {1,...,7}{\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\x,.15) node [ ]{} -- (\incrmnt*\x,-.15) node [below] {\x} ;}

% left graph
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, draw, solid, red, fill=red, scale=0.4}]
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*1,\incrmnt*1) node{} -- (\incrmnt,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*2,\incrmnt*2) node{}-- (\incrmnt*2,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*3,\incrmnt*2) node{} -- (\incrmnt*3,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*4,\incrmnt*2) node{} -- (\incrmnt*4,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*5,\incrmnt*2) node{} -- (\incrmnt*5,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*6,\incrmnt*2) node{} -- (\incrmnt*6,.15);
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*7,\incrmnt*1) node {} -- (\incrmnt*7,.15);
\end{scope}

%do the same with the second right graph, plot the same axis by a simple 8cm translation 
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw [thick,-latex](-2,0)node [below right] {$-\infty$}   -- (6,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3)  -- (0,8);
\foreach \y in {1,...,12}{\draw [linecolor] (0,\incrmnt*\y) +(0:.15cm) -- +(180:.15cm) node [left] {\y/12};
\draw [dotline] (0,\incrmnt*\y) -- +(0:10*\incrmnt);}
\foreach \x in {1,...,7}{\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\x,.15) -- (\incrmnt*\x,-.15) node [below] {\x};}

% right graph
\draw [thick, black] (\incrmnt*9,0) node [below] {$\infty$} --+(0,\incrmnt*13);
\foreach \x in {1,...,6}{\draw[ultra thick, blue](\incrmnt*\x,{\incrmnt*(2*\x-1)})node[point]{}--+(\incrmnt,0)node[cercle]{};}
\node[cercle] at(\incrmnt,0){};
\draw[ultra thick, blue](\incrmnt*7,\incrmnt*12)node[point]{}--+(\incrmnt*2,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had known where the journey will go when I answered your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457159/simplifying-repetitive-drawings-and-node-placing) what I knew when I wrote [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458075/121799), I would have recommended pgfplots back then. But given that you seem not to like pgfplots, I provide you loops once more. Nevertheless I can't refrain from asking you to at least consider using pgfplots for that. You'd never have to multiply everything by clumsy units and scale factors, not have to deal with loops that draw the plots or add ticks and so on. (And no, sadly I am not willing to just translate the following quickly to pgfplots "for fun".)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{linecolor/.style={ultra thick, green!40!black},dotline/.style={thin, black, loosely dotted},
point/.style={circle, draw, red, fill=red, scale=0.4},
cercle/.style={circle,draw,scale=.5, red,thick, fill=white,inner sep=6pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{First drawing (unchanged)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.6}

\draw [thick,-latex](-.3,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3)  -- (0,8);
\draw [thick,-latex](6.,0)  -- (14.4,0) coordinate (br);
\draw [thick,-latex](8,-.2) -- (8,8) coordinate(tr);
\foreach \X in {1,...,12}
{
\draw [dotline] (0,\X*7cm/12) -- ++ (14,0);
\draw [linecolor] (-\incrmnt/2,\X*7cm/12)node[left]{\X/12} -- ++ (\incrmnt,0)
(8-\incrmnt/2,\X*7cm/12)node[left]{\X/12}-- ++ (\incrmnt,0);
}
\foreach \X in {1,...,7}
{
\draw[linecolor]  (3*\X/5,-\incrmnt/2) node[below]{\X} -- ++ (0,\incrmnt)
(8+3*\X/5,-\incrmnt/2) node[below]{\X} -- ++ (0,\incrmnt);
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tst}{abs(\X-4)}
\ifnum\tst=3
\draw[linecolor]  (3*\X/5,0)  -- ++ (0,7/12)
node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{};
\else
\draw[linecolor]  (3*\X/5,0)  -- ++ (0,14/12)
node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{};
\fi
\ifnum\X=7
\draw[blue,thick]   (8+3*\X/5,{7*(2*\X-2)/12})
node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{} -- ++ (2*7cm/12,0) coordinate(xr);
\else
\draw[blue,thick]  (8+3*\X/5,{7*(2*\X-1)/12}) node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{}
-- ++ (1*7cm/12,0) node[circle,fill=white,draw=red,inner sep=2pt]{};
\fi
}
\draw (tr-|xr) -- (br-|xr) node[below](ir){$\infty$};
\node at (6.5,0 |-ir) {$-\infty$};
\node[circle,fill=white,draw=red,inner sep=2pt,thick] at (8+3/5,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Second drawing: cdf1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.6}

\draw [thick,-latex](-.3,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3)  -- (0,8);
\draw [thick,-latex](6.,0)  -- (14.4,0) coordinate (br);
\draw [thick,-latex](8,-.2) -- (8,8) coordinate(tr);
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(3*\X)}]in {2,4,...,12}
{
\draw [dotline] (0,\X*7cm/12) -- ++ (14,0);
\draw [linecolor] (-\incrmnt/2,\X*7cm/12)node[left]{\X/36} -- ++ (\incrmnt,0)
(8-\incrmnt/2,\X*7cm/12)node[left]{\Y/36}-- ++ (\incrmnt,0);
}
\def\hs{{3,5,4,3,2,1}}
\foreach \X in {0,...,5}
{
\draw[linecolor]  ({3*(\X+1)/4},-\incrmnt/2) node[below]{\X} -- ++ (0,\incrmnt)
({8+3*(\X+1)/4},-\incrmnt/2) node[below]{\X} -- ++ (0,\incrmnt);
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\h}{\hs[\X]}
\draw[linecolor]  ({3*(\X+1)/4},0)  -- ++ (0,7*\h/6);
\draw[blue,thick]  ({8+3*(\X+1)/4},{7*(2*\X+2)/12}) node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{}
-- ++ (3/4,0) node[circle,fill=white,draw=red,inner sep=2pt] (aux){};
\ifnum\X<5
\draw[cyan,thick] (aux) -- ++ (0,7/6);
\fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Third drawing: cdf2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{.6}

\draw [thick,-latex](-.3,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-.3)  -- (0,8);
\draw [thick,-latex](6.,0)  -- (14.4,0) coordinate (br);
\draw [thick,-latex](8,-.2) -- (8,8) coordinate(tr);
\foreach \X in {1,...,8}
{
\draw [dotline] (0,\X*7/8) -- ++ (14,0);
\ifnum\X=8
\draw [linecolor] (-\incrmnt/2,\X*7/8)node[left]{1} -- ++ (\incrmnt,0)
(8-\incrmnt/2,\X*7/8)node[left]{1}-- ++ (\incrmnt,0);
\else
\draw [linecolor] (-\incrmnt/2,\X*7/8)node[left]{\X/8} -- ++ (\incrmnt,0)
(8-\incrmnt/2,\X*7/8)node[left]{\X/8}-- ++ (\incrmnt,0);
\fi
}
\def\hs{{1,3,3,1}}
\def\sumh{0}
\foreach \X in {0,...,3}
{
\draw[linecolor]  
({\X+1},-\incrmnt/2) node[below]{\X} -- ++ (0,\incrmnt)
({8+\X+1},-\incrmnt/2) node[below]{\X} -- ++ (0,\incrmnt);
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\h}{\hs[\X]}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\oldsumh}{\sumh}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\sumh}{\sumh+\h}
\xdef\sumh{\sumh}
\draw[linecolor]  ({\X+1},0)  -- ++ (0,7*\h/8) 
node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt]{};
\draw[cyan,latex-latex]  ({8+\X+1},{7*\oldsumh/8}) 
node[circle,fill=white,draw=red,inner sep=2pt]{} 
-- ({8+\X+1},{7*\sumh/8})node[fill,red,circle,inner sep=2pt] (aux){}
node[midway,right,black]{$P_{(\X)}$};
\ifnum\X=3
\draw[blue,thick] (aux) -- ++ (14/8,0) coordinate (r);
\else
\draw[blue,thick] (aux) -- ++ (7/8,0);
\fi
}
\draw (r |- 14,8) -- (r|-14,0)node[below]{$\infty$};
\node at (6.5,0 |-ir) {$-\infty$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again; but in the cdf1 middle graph, there is a missing  connecting cyan line from the x axis to the first red dot (red fill red). I could not figure out how to add it (please refer to my original drawing). I also would like to decrease the vertical dimension of the whole graph. Thank you.

Comment: @Hany Just add `\draw[cyan,thick] (8+3/4,0) -- ++ (0,7/6);` before the corresponding `\end{tikzpicture}`.